# get content of http request in REST web service using java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, httprequest

Anyone know how to get content of httprequest in REST webservice using java?

thanks

Comment: what have you used to implement webservice?

Answer (score 3):

You can inject context about the individual requests. As an example, the code snippet below shows how the HTTP request headers can be injected.

```
@GET  
@Produces{"text/plain"}  
public String listHeaderNames(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {  
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();  
  for (String header: headers.getRequestHeaders().keySet()) {  
    buf.append(header);  
    buf.append("\n");  
  }  
  return buf.toString();  
}
```

See the [relevant part](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-520005) of the JAX-RS 1.1 specification for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Restlet](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/320-restlet.html)

```
// Create the client resource  
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://www.restlet.org");  

// Write the response entity on the console
resource.get().write(System.out);
```